# The layout of a menu screen gets rearranged and messed up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

When I run the app and three of the text views get filled with text, the textviews get rearranged and the whole layout is messed up. In the sdk, the layout is how it is supposed to be, but once the app runs and the textviews get filled with text, the layout gets messed up. I think this has to do with it being a relative layout, not sure though. Can someone help me fix this? Thanks
Here is my XML Code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.firstapp.Menu$PlaceholderFragment" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Main Menu"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:text="Logout" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Courses" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="User Type:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/organization"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/organization"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="Organization:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usertype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/organization"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/usertype"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usertype"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/organization"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:text="LogOut" />
```

Comment: First off, button1 is missing the <Button tag at the start of it's declaration.

Comment: where? I see the <Button at the start, maybe im looking somewhere else

Comment: Look at the code in your post. After you end the first TextView code block with 'textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />' your next line is 'android:id="@+id/button1"'

Comment: You've done the same in the RelativeLayout definition. You've closed the block off at the end of the 5th line where you define the background, so all those lines about the padding etc are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to use a view in a relative relation before you've defined it.
For example, you define in textView2, that `layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"` before you've defined textView4.
Relative layout is good for building flexible layouts, but you still need to build it in a logical manner, by defining new views relative to already existing views only.

Define view 1 relative to the root layout.
Define view 2 relative to view 1 or to the root layout.
Define view 3 relative to view 1, 2 or the root layout.
etc

---

Additional:
Think of it this way. Imagine an empty table.

..I give you a red block and tell you to put it in the middle of the table.
    ..You do so.

..I give you a white block and tell you to put it to the right of the red block.
    ..Again, you do so.

..I give you a green block and tell you to put it on top of the white block.
    ..Once again, no problems. You do so.

..I give you a blue block and tell you to put it to the left of the purple block.
    ..You say "I can't!! There's no purple block here!!"

Comment: As I said in my answer, just make sure that when you scroll down through the XML, each view you've added only depends on views that have already been defined earlier on in the XML layout.